# Getting conflict errors when installing nagios on centos

Tags: php, linux, centos, nagios

Getting below error when installing nagios on centOS (CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)). How to resolve these?

```
Error: php72u-common conflicts with php56u-common-5.6.37-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
Error: php72u-pdo conflicts with php56u-pdo-5.6.37-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
Error: Package: perl-Mail-IMAPClient-3.37-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: perl(Parse::RecDescent)
Error: php72u-xml conflicts with php56u-xml-5.6.37-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
Error: Package: rrdtool-1.4.9-1.el7.x86_64 (nagiosxi-deps)
       Requires: dejavu-lgc-sans-mono-fonts
Error: php72u-cli conflicts with php56u-cli-5.6.37-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
Error: Package: nagiosxi-deps-el7-5.5.3-1.noarch (/nagiosxi-deps-el7-5.5.3-1.noarch)
       Requires: net-snmp-perl
Error: Package: nagiosxi-deps-el7-5.5.3-1.noarch (/nagiosxi-deps-el7-5.5.3-1.noarch)
       Requires: gd-devel
Error: Package: dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts-2.33-1.el6.noarch (installed)
       Requires: dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-1.el6
       Removing: dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-1.el6.noarch (installed)
           dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-1.el6
       Updated By: dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-6.el7.noarch (RHEL7_u4)
           dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-6.el7
```

Comment: Well, aren't those messages crystal clear? They clearly state that you have a conflict between two versions of php. You already have installed php in version 5.6 and now dependency resolution tries to install version 7.2. So the solution probably is to remove the existing php installation or upgrade it manually. Maybe you even have marked that old version as to be kept, you will have to check that.

Comment: Thanks. How do i install the dejavu-fonts as a package? when i install individual rpm files it says some other rpm dependents are required. So this is getting multiplied on the dependent files count. So how do i install the dejavu package with dependent files at one go?

Comment: You simply specify the packages to install in one command. In the case of CentOS that would be the rpm packages.

Comment: If i am downloading one rpm file and when trying to install using rpm -i packagename, then i am getting message that the dependent rpm files are required. And those dependent rpm asks for some other dependent files. So this is becoming huge task.